# Customize Data Grid View in Windows Form

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, datagridview, accounting

Like this

[image: 1]

how can I customize datagridview to be like this photo in like
which means its start with full empty rows, like in accounting programs

Comment: _full empty rows_ What does that mean? A screenful? A maximum number? Virtual rows? And why? Or do mean the colors? Very unclear..

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would not recommend that you do this.  Most good accounting programs don't do it either!

That said, the first way to do it would be to create a suitable set of data with the required number of rows already in it and then assign that as the data source. If you go beyone the available list then add a new row to the datasource.

The second way to do it would be to subclass DataGridView and handle the drawing yourself to draw the grid to mimic the rows.

I cannot recommend either option, and would recommend simply allowing new rows to be automatically added as the user enters something in the 'new' row. This is the way that most good programs do it.

Comment: your suggest is highly appricated ,but i use this way because intry journal maybe have more than record

Comment: Indeed. That is the WHOLE POINT of my recommendation.  If you use the method I recommend new rows will be added automatically as needed, without limitation other than system resources. After all, what is the point of having rows you don't want to process?  You would have to read them and discard them when saving or just draw them either of which is a waste of valuable resources. The DataGridView is designed to extendable...

Comment: I agree with you and your recommendations are highly appreciated